# How to show ubuntu desktop

Tags: 18.04, taskbar

When I start Ubuntu 18.04 I only see this screen which is in photo and no other option is available, could you tell me what is the exact issue?

[image: accops sign-in]

Comment: Are you sure this is a standard ubuntu 18.04 install and not some kind of a vm or vm server? That is not a standard ubuntu desktop login.

Comment: I hv already install ubuntu but 2 days ago I hv installed one application accops, after that my hole aplication is blank

Answer (score 0):

Looks like accops software is installed on the machine. Try entering your password and access. I guess should be able to see the screen then.

Comment: I want to uninstall this application but not to get any option